# Why does t5 tokenizer may sometimes output the ▁ as a separate token from the following word?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, large-language-model, huggingface-tokenizers

I fine-tuned my T5-model on a dataset, and when I plot my heat map attention, I see some weird behavior in the tokenizer. For example in the attached picture, the underscore and "eat" are on separate rows as well as _ and "he", while other underscores and words are on the same rows. What is causing this behavior, is this a bug? [image]